# How to run a file in a new window in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to run the java file in a new window
IntelliJ IDEA. If I run this file with the project open, the file opens in it, and not in a new window

I tried to open by opening the folder with the file in IntelliJ IDEA, but this only works if some project is already opened in IntelliJ IDEA, otherwise only the project opens, but the file does not.

"path to idea" "path to project" && "path to idea" "path to java file"

Comment: Didn't hear about such option, what is the use case?

Comment: I need to open a java project from javascript with a specific file in Idea